# Choosing display magnification

Tags: windows-7, windows

I wish to change magnification on different pages on my laptop.
My old windows XP desktop has a 100% box on the LOWER RIGHT corner of every page.
How can I have that same feature [100% box] on my windows 7 laptop ??

Comment: What do you mean with "lower right corner *of every page*"? Which pages?

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
2. Click on *Start Magnifier*
3. Click on *Views* and choose *Docked* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

You can click into the magnifier window and move it where you want,  also to the lower right corner of the screen.

[image]

Comment: I allowed me to confirm your translated texts & inserted an image. Since the OP doesn't respond I'm still unsure what he exactly wants.